# How to change the content of all the tags with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JQuery to change the content of all the `.valueInput` tags with a string.
Here is my code, which doesn't seem to do anything:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p4yvq0vp/2/

**html**

```
<div class='main'>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$document.ready(function() {
  $('.valueInput').text('hi');
});
```

Comment: Missing `(` `)` around **document** https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

Change `$document` to `$(document)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.valueInput').each(function() {
    $(this).text('hi!');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuz5ygur/